# How to use Mule's XML-to-Object transformer?

Tags: java, xml, object, mule, xstream

What are the steps which should be done? What should be present in the driver class? How should I create the POJO with which to map the XML to? How should I configure the transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a driver class like Xpp3driver

eg.

the flow would look something like

```
<flow name="mulexmlvalFlow2" doc:name="mulexmlvalFlow2">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" path="XmlToObj"/>
        <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object" driverClass="com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.Xpp3Driver">
            <mulexml:alias name="Abc" class="a.b.c.Abc" />        
        </mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer>
        <component class="Test1" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

http request

```
http://localhost:8082/XmlToObj
```

headers
Content-Type  application/xml
post data

```
<Abc><def>ggggg</def><ghi>hhhhh</ghi></Abc>
```

ABC class

```
package a.b.c.Abc;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Abc")
public class Abc{
private String def;
private String ghi;

public Abc() {
}

public String getDef() {
    return def;
}
public void setDef(String def) {
    this.def = def;
}
public String getGhi() {
    return ghi;
}
public void setGhi(String ghi) {
    this.ghi = ghi;
}

}
```

Class Test1 (component)

```
public class Test1 {

    public Object receive(Abc abc) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(abc);
        return "Success";
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the component class be `Abc`instead of `Test1`?

Comment: When I tried the example, I got the following error:
`Exception stack is:
1. Abc (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException)
  com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper:56 (null)
2. Abc (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToObject:72 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)`

Comment: no Test1 is a component which can handle the request. Updating the answer with Test1.

Comment: I added the Test1 component but I am still getting the error I mentioned above.

Comment: My client is:
`$.post("http://localhost:8082/XmlToObj",
"<Abc><def>ggggg</def><ghi>hhhhh</ghi></Abc>",
function(data,status){
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});`

Comment: i'm using postman rest client.. and also have Content-Type application/xml

Comment: It's the weekend. I will check on Monday and inform you.

Comment: I had added the class in a package and the xml did not contain the full class name. That is why I was getting the error. Is there any way for the transformer to look into a particular package to search for the object?